# React Native : onChangeText how to handle two events?

Tags: react-native

I am making a upload user introduction function ,
the idea is :

1. the input box of introduction is able to add a characters count ;
2. and is able to use formik to upload also ..

I have noticed that ,the onChangeText only able to handle one event once ..therefore ,I made a function ,in order to handle two events ...
However ,it dose't work ..

Could you please take a look my code ?
Thank you so much !

[image]

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,View,Text } from 'react-native';
import ErrorMsg from './ErrorMsg';
import { useFormikContext } from 'formik';
import AppTextInput from './AppTextInput';
import colors from '../config/colors';


function AppFormFliedUserInfo({name,width='90%',number,style,...otherProps}) {
   const{setFieldTouched, handleChange, errors, touched }= useFormikContext();
   const [value,setValue] = useState('');
   
  function twoCalls(name){
      handleChange(name);
       setValue(text);
  }
  
    return (
        <View style={[styles.container,{width:width} ,style]}>
        <View style={styles.first_container}>
        <ErrorMsg error={errors[name]} visible={touched[name]}/>
        <AppTextInput
        onBlur = {()=>setFieldTouched(name)}
        onChangeText = {twoCalls}
        width = {width}
        number ={number}
        maxLength={number}
        {...otherProps}
        />
        </View>
         {/**Count */}
       {number&&(
            <View style={styles.count_container}>
          <Text>{value === "" ? "0" : value.length}/{number}</Text>
            </View>
       )}
            
        </View>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    count_container : {
        width : "100%",
        alignItems : 'flex-end',
        marginTop : 10,
    },
    container :{
        padding: 15,
        flexDirection: "column",
        marginVertical : 10,
        borderRadius: 25,
        backgroundColor: colors.light,
    },
    first_container : {
        flexDirection : "row",
        flex : 1,
       
    },
})
export default AppFormFliedUserInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's just a typo:

```
 function twoCalls(name){
      handleChange(name);
       setValue(name);  //Change "text" to "name"
  }
```

Comment: Hello my friend ,thank you sooo much for your advise .I have tried ,it works the  setValue(name)  ;how ever it dosen't work the handleChange(name) ; Could you please check it out again ? Thank you so much for your patience.